# svn: '.' is not a working copy directory

Tags: svn

I'm new to svn. I had to move svn repos from ec2 instance to another one. I wanted to reconstruct the svn from the exiting repos. I ran the command `svn recover` and got the recovery going. However, I cannot get a working copy out of these repos.
When I ran `sudo svnlook tree /home/svndir/repos/****` I could see the repository but I could not make a working copy out of these recovered repos. can anybody help me?

Comment: 1. Why you recover not-broken repo? 2 Show results (full) of `svn co <REPO-URL>`